# I'm willing to make the discord bot send all the messages (join, leave, kill, chat) from my minecraft bot

Tags: javascript, minecraft, discord.js

On message event isn't working and it doesn't send the messages to the specified discord channel.

I've been trying to get it to work I tried on chat and it worked but it didn't send the join/leave nor sent the kill messages.

```js
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const connect = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "25567",
    "username": "MegaREEE"
}
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
host: connect.host,
    port: connect.port,
    username: connect.username,
  });
  client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("succesfully connected to discord")
    client.channels.get("593310885729271859").send("✔: Bot Connected!")
  })
  bot.on('messsage', function(jsonMsg) {
    client.channels.get("593310885729271859").send(jsonMsg)
  })
    client.login(token)
```

Comment: Are you sure the channel is there and it's ID remains same?

Comment: Probably the format of `jsonMsg` you get from your mineflayer bot isn't handled by what you can send to your discord bot, try to send a string: ` client.channels.get("593310885729271859").send(JSON.stringify(jsonMsg))`

Comment: it didn't work I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsonMsg` has to be a string, not an object. Whatever gets put into `send` must be either a Message String to send to Discord, or an Embed Object which you can read about over on the Discord API Documentation. https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object

EDIT: After checking Mineflayer's API, play joined/left events don't pass through message, rather they pass through `playerJoined` and `playerLeft` events. See https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md#playerjoined-player

Comment: i even tried to log it in console... it didn't work either

Comment: After checking mineflayer's API, those events dont pass through "message", instead you use playerJoined, or playerLeft. See https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md#playerjoined-player

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it but had to change a lot in the code I added the following:

```
    minecraftBot.on('message', (message) => {
        let log = message.text;
        if (message.extra){
            log += message.extra.map(it => it.text).join("");
        }
        log = log.trim();
        if (log.length === 0){ return; }
        channel.send("", {
            embed: new djs.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(mflConf.host)
            .setDescription(`**${log}**`)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(moment().format('h:mm:ss a')+ " © Syndicate Bot.")
        });
    });
```